# How to run colab notebook in previous environment?

Tags: google-colaboratory

My jupyter notebook hosted on Colab has recently changed behaviour, in particular

- ipywidget outputs no longer nest correctly
- `interactive_output` appends new outputs rather then replacing the output
- matplotlib figure sizes have become enormous
- I receive various DeprecationWarnings from pandas

I presume this is due to an upgrade of pandas, ipywidgets and possibly jupyter on the backend.

Is there any way to specify that I would like my notebook to run with the colab environment exactly as it was 2 months ago?

Edit: I have found the googlegolab/backend-info git repo. I presume previous versions of requirements.txt could in principle be installed, albeit at the cost of hugely increasing runtime every time the notebook is started, or needing large amounts of space on a google drive. I guess what I'm asking is, is there a ready-to-roll environment I can ask colab to use instead of the latest one?